# How to add id for hidden field oscommerce(tep_draw_hidden_field)

Tags: php, html, web, oscommerce

I want this input field convert to hidden field include id

```
<?php echo TEXT_CHOOSE_SHIPPING_DATE . '<br /><br />' . tep_draw_input_field('delivery_date','', 'id="delivery_date"'); ?>
```

below Code not working

```
<?php echo TEXT_CHOOSE_SHIPPING_DATE . '<br /><br />' . tep_draw_hidden_field('delivery_date','', 'id="delivery_date"'); ?>
```

Please help!

Comment: Your code looks correct to me.  How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Is it a sin to use native php apis? Why not `<?php echo TEXT_CHOOSE_SHIPPING_DATE . '<br /><br /><input type="hidden" name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date"/>' ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code and it's working properly:

```
tep_draw_input_field('coupon', '', 'size="32"    id="discount_coupon_id"', $coupon);
```